# Display a text file content in C++ windows program

Tags: c++, display

I am trying to display a text file content. I am using C++ fstream library to create the file and write in it and I am in Windows environment. The IDE that I am using is Visual Studio 2008. Is there any windows API of any sort that I can use which will open the text file and display the content automatically when my program terminates.

If any one else has any other approach in mind, feel free to mention them as well.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Display it how? In a console application, you can just write it to `std::cout`. In a GUI application, you can create a window with a text field. In either, you can just run `notepad.exe <name_of_file>` :)

Comment: Hi.. I have found a solution for this one.. May be this will clarify.. I am creating a .txt file using fstream.. Updating it using the fstream object or the file handler.. Now i will close it.. and write system("notepad.exe filepath").. this "system" call will open the document automatically after the program has run successfully..

Comment: any other suggestions are also welcome..

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be to open the file in Notepad++ and after running the program if the file has changed, Notepad++ usually asks if you want to reload the file. This updates the view in notepad++. hopefully this is something you were looking for.

Comment: but the txt file contains metadata that is created during the program runs.. so i do not think opening notepad++ before running the program would be a wise approach.. cannot ask the client to do something like this..ur idea is good.. but will not be suitable for the users..